# Blender hard freezes pc when rendering this file

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I've been following a [realistic earth tutorial](https://youtu.be/0YZzHn0iz8U) (to learn the software), and attempting to render the image instantly freezes my pc so hard the only option is to unplug it. It has also just been crashing randomly, not just this file,  for absolutely no reason. I have attached the file here if you want to look for anything wrong. (hopefully, it uploads)

[image]

Comment: In this tutorial, two 8k and two 10k image textures are used. That's huge and consumes a lot of memory. I've just [rendered the earth](https://imgur.com/X8RGyVq) and Blender was at 12 GB RAM usage. If your PC does not have that much memory, you can scale down the images in an image editor like Gimp. A 8k image is 4 times bigger than a 4k image (because of width x height) and 16 times bigger than a 2k image which is roughly what a full HD TV screen can display. Try to scale the images down to 50% or even 25% and try again.

Comment: Here the comparison of the rendered image vs the 8k texture: https://ibb.co/HDTr3v6

Comment: Thanks! I tried using some of the lower textures and everything is working fine. My pc doesn't have a ton of memory so that was probably why.